# Awkward selecting by keyboard

Tags: editing

How can you modify text selection using [shift][right arrow]? The standard behaviour is awful: when I select too far and want to go back one step using [shift][left arrow] it extends the selection on the left, rather than unselecting from the right.

As far as I can tell nobody knows how to do this, as this old post in another forum, lamenting the same problem, never got a reply:

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/mathematica-text-selection-behavior.217967/

Comment: Which version are you using? There's no such problem with `10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)`.

Comment: It was indeed like that in the past, but it has changed a long time ago. Version 9 already has a modern selection behaviour. The current version is 11.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica 8 (released in Novermber 2010) already has the the usual modern selection behaviour.  Earlier versions had the behaviour you describe.  The easiest solution is to upgrade.

Reference:

- http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Nov/msg00587.html